# Python, entry point of opensfm?

Tags: python

I'm not a Python expert but I've to learn how to use it.
I have a tool to look through, which I've installed and works perfectly but I have a very silly/stupid/noob question:

[This](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/blob/master/bin/opensfm_run_all) script runs [this](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/blob/master/opensfm/commands/extract_metadata.py) as very first command, but I cannot see any main etc. And therefore I'm not sure how exactly this works, there's no main function etc, it seems to me that the class Command actually embeds the whole entry point.

Is this correct?

For example I've tried to reproduce the structure in the following way:

File script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

$DIR/ helloWorld $1
```

File .py

```
import os;

class Command:
   name = "HelloWorld"
   help = "Test"

   def run(self,args):
       print "hello world!"
```

I'm sure I've also problems with imports etc...
I'm just trying to write down some very simple examples for future references.

Comment: Python doesn't need a main. It can have one, but it's behaviour without one is just start interpreting the scripts from the first line, and going down. I'm surprised, you said you've learnt how to use it but this is usually the very first feature somebody learns about Python.

Comment: Nono I'm aware it is a script language, maybe if I post a very silly sample of what I'm trying to do it would be better.

Comment: Well your question was if the class Command embeds the whole entry point. But if no Command is created anywhere, it will just execute the two lines before it, and that's all.

Comment: Yeah exactly, Command is a class, so it won't just run because it's the next line, you need to create a `Command` and then execute `run('whatever')`

Comment: But my actual question is that I don't see any object istantiated in opensfm, and neither an explicit call to `run`, in the `opensfm_run_all` script. This is what confuses me.

Comment: I haven't used that so probably somebody else could help more, but I suppose that it's just not necessary there, but maybe it's used somewhere else by another script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [this](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/blob/master/bin/opensfm) as runner (lines 32:34 are responsible for running)

in bash script line 
`$DIR/opensfm extract_metadata` will exec `opensfm` form `bin ($DIR)` with param `extract_metadata`

Comment: As I said... noob question. Thank you.